Link - React Router Dom does not call to Backend
I'm using Link to create a HashTag like images below


It works for the first click, after that it just changes the browser URL and doesn't make request to backend.
I checked the browser's Network tab; it only made a favicon.ico request with a 304 Not Modified status. Given this status, I think there are some reasons that make ReactJS think the data has been loaded, but I cannot find documentation about that. Can you please explain or provide some documents about this issue?

Link is used to redirect from one page to another without refreshing as react is single page application so for data fetching Please go through https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-fetch-api-data-in-react/ or use react-query for more powerful asynchronous state management.

If you need to make Backend requests, it is not best practice to access the backend URL via the URL its self. You should use fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or a library like axios for example. With fetch you can use the backend URL and make your request. If you implement it correctly, you shouldnt have any problems.

Oh, in my Tag component (path /tags/:slug), I'm using Axios (as your recommendation) in useEffect hook, but my dependencies list is empty. That's why it just load for the first time!
